# String replace after XMLWriter in php, before flush()

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I produced a very complex XML (with XMLWriter for PHP) coming from a pretty long MySQL statement (with 4 inner join, thanks to the weird Prestashop tables organization) and I am almost pretty happy with the resulting file.
However, I'd like to have the chance that, after built the XML, let's say before XML->flush() I can do some basic string find and replace.

Is this possible? I am aware of XMLWriter, XMLReader, SimpleXML, but what I am asking is just to to do some string replace with PHP on the XML file I am building, before flush().

Any idea?
Thanks
Fabio

Comment: `XMLWriter::outputMemory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two ways to go about this.

1. Do the find/replace after a call to `flush`.
2. Every place you are calling the various [writer functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xmlwriter-write-comment.php), run `$content` through your find/replace logic before passing it to the writer function.

A word of caution, string replacements on xml could be a bad idea, especially regex. Maybe consider xpath after a call to `flush`, or if you know you're operating on the content of tags or attribute names/values only before calling writers, it could be best to do the find/replace calls there.

**EDIT**
Here is an example. This is just one way, but it's a simple example; see if it helps.

```
$writer = new XMLWriter(); 

$writer->openMemory();
$writer->startDocument('1.0'); 
$writer->setIndent(4); 
$writer->startElement('rss'); 
$writer->writeAttribute('version', '2.0'); 
$writer->writeAttribute('xmlns:atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'); 
$writer->startElement("channel"); 
$writer->writeElement('title', 'Latest Products'); 
$writer->endElement(); 
$writer->endElement(); 
$writer->endDocument(); 

$doc = $writer->flush(); 
$doc = str_replace('Latest Products', "Nathan's Products", $doc);
echo $doc;
```

Comment: Dear, thank you for your time and the reply. If I use outputMemory to get a string, then I can not modify it...

    $result = $xml->outputMemory(); 

// or $result = $xml->flush();

    str_replace("Marocco","Marokko",$result);

    echo  $result;

You write to do a find/replace after flush(), but on which string? How can I get a string from XMLWriter, unless I do like I showed?

Comment: Brilliant explanation. You saved my day! Thank you very much!